# Using Action(Of... as settings parameter

Tags: vb.net

I've seen code like this..

```
Public Sub Test()
    Call Init(Sub(s)
                  s.Width = 100
              End Sub)
End Sub
```

But I can't figure out how to use action as a settings parameter.

Here's my code:

```
Public Class SettingsModel
    Public Property Width As Integer = 0
End Class

Public Sub Init(settings As Action(Of SettingsModel))
    Dim ac As SettingsModel = Activator.CreateInstance(Of SettingsModel)
    Console.WriteLine(ac.Width)
End Sub
```

But at my Console.WriteLine(ac.Width), I expect the value to be 100, but the value is 0.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `Any idea what I am doing wrong?` - you never call the passed `settings` lambda?

Comment: Doesn't I do that in the ... Call Init(Sub(s)
                  s.Width = 100
              End Sub) .. ?

Comment: That passes the lambda to `Init`. The lambda cannot execute at the time of passing because it is not how the language works and because at that point there is no instance of `SettingsModel` that it accepts as a parameter. You need to call it explicitly from `Init` and pass `ac` to it.

Comment: Oh thanks ... I was .... SO CLOSE :)

Comment: @MojoDK - Please put your solution as your own answer to the question. Don't edit your question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution ... I need to call the settings(ac)...

```
Public Sub Init(settings As Action(Of SettingsModel))
    Dim ac As SettingsModel = Activator.CreateInstance(Of SettingsModel)
    settings(ac)
    Console.WriteLine(ac.Width)
End Sub
```